# Add shared OneDrive folder to my OneDrive for Business and not my OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I am collaborating with several other people on a project for work. We want to use OneDrive to manage the file sharing. I have received an invitation to share and edit a folder from one of my collaborators. When I click on "Add to My OneDrive" or "Add to my shared list", I am prompted to log in to my Microsoft account. When I try to log in with my Office365/OneDrive for Business credentials given to me by my employer, I get the error that it is not a valid Microsoft account/password.

I do not want to mix my personal and work OneDrives. I also expect that this project might exceed the free OneDrive space allocated to my Microsoft Live account, which began its existence as an Xbox Live account. This account also does not have full Office 365 access. How can I get this folder to be added to my OneDrive for Business and not my OneDrive? Is there a way from within OneDrive for Business (or the client) to open a shared link directly after I have logged in?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the OneDrive for Business App installed as well?

OneDrive and OneDrive for Business are different in every way.  ODFB is based on Sharepoint.  Your oneDrive for Business account will not log into the OD app or webmail, and the opposite is of course also true.

Just to clarify, this project is not for work, and they plan to use oneDrive, not ODFB, correct?  In that case, you won't be able to use O365 login, and you also cannot be logged into more than one onedrive account on either app.

Comment: I am using the "Next Generation" One Drive client on Windows 10, which handles both One Drive and One Drive for Business. Which app/client is installed is a moot point since trying to open the link sent to me takes me to a website. This is a project for work and I want to use my Office 365 / One Drive for Business with it.

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive sync client doesn't yet support on-premises instances of OneDrive for Business (when your organization doesn't subscribe to an Office 365 business plan). Can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49).

It sounds like you need to get the separate OD apps.